# jQuery - return false & append text to DIV

Tags: jquery, language-agnostic, functional-programming, return-value, return-path

Something in my code isn't working and I'm not sure what it is.  I want this function to return false, and at the same time append some text to a DIV

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#newCatchForm').submit(function() {
    if ( !$('#t1')[0].value && !$('#t2')[0].value ) { 
        return false;
        $('#divTest').append("this text was appended");
 }
});
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

return halts execution. Nothing else will get executed after return...

switch the two around:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#newCatchForm').submit(function() {
    if ( !$('#t1')[0].value && !$('#t2')[0].value ) {
      $('#divTest').append("this text was appended");
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The `return` statement doesn't only determine the return value, it also exits from the function, so you should put that last:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#newCatchForm').submit(function() {
    if ( !$('#t1')[0].value && !$('#t2')[0].value ) { 
      $('#divTest').append("this text was appended");
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`return false` will stop the execution of the function, therefore the next instruction will never be executed. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#newCatchForm').submit(function() {
        if ( !$('#t1')[0].value && !$('#t2')[0].value ) { 
            $('#divTest').append("this text was appended");
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```